# Simple URL to fire javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I need to fire this javascript function:

```
window.icegram.get_message_by_id(2072).show();
```

From a plain URL (e.g. www.google.com/? etc) as I cannot edit the HTML, as shown in this image:

[image]

I have tried to use this code in that URL field:

```
javascript:window.icegram.get_message_by_id(2072).show();
```

But when I click on the button, it says "Uncaught TypeError" and that the function is unknown.

For reference purposes, the Icegram documentation says that you can trigger the popup by using either using (both work on a Wordpress post):

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.icegram.get_message_by_id(6344).show();">Your text</a>
```

OR

```
[icegram campaigns="XXXX"]<a href="#">Your Text</a> [/icegram]
```

Maybe I could call the javascript function by including it in a separate file first? I would appreciate any help, I have tried and researched for a couple hours.

I can confirm that it adds the javascript section in the correct place -

[image]

does this mean that there is an issue with my javascript function, perhaps its not working properly? Confusing as it does work on a wordpress post (when using the full "a href=" code) but when I use the function it instantly says -

[image]

Comment: As a bookmarklet you need to get rid of the quotes: `javascript:window.icegram.get_message_by_id(2072).show();` but if that returns anything you need to do `javascript:(function() {window.icegram.get_message_by_id(2072).show();})()`

Comment: Apologies, that was actually a typo, I did try without the quotes so I have updated the question. I just tried your second suggestion, I get this error message (also unknown but see image) - http://imgur.com/a/EksvB

Comment: If the end result `<a href="javascript:yourfunctionhere()">hello</a>` works and filling in the form will insert such a link, then it should work. Perhaps you can hit F12 and see what the link looks like after submitting the form?

Comment: Open developer console with your page open, type in `window.icegram.get_message_by_id(2072).show()` or `window.icegram` and see what it shows.

Comment: I can confirm that it adds the javascript section in the correct place - https://imgur.com/a/EH4jL - does this mean that there is an issue with my javascript function, perhaps its not working properly? Confusing as it does work on a wordpress post (when using the full "a href=" code). I will try that @sabithpocker - UPDATE: It instantly says - https://imgur.com/a/MJwhm

Comment: try `....byId('2072')` with quotes and also try to find something with id="2072"

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it seems that Icegram has a bug, in which the function ID used in the shortcode (e.g. 2072) is different from the function ID needed when calling using javascript (wtf), which in this case was 2073.

So if anyone else needs it, this is the solution for a plain URL field:

```
javascript:icegram.get_message_by_id(2073).show();
```

which results in the following output when viewed live on the frontend:

```
<a href="javascript:icegram.get_message_by_id(2073).show();" class="et_pb_more_button" rel="nofollow">Your Anchor Text</a>
```

I hope that helps someone. A big thank you to mplungjan and sabithpocker for the guidance and responses.